# Exception was caught during Core Data change processing, attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)

Tags: ios, swift, exception, core-data, runtime-error

I'm using coreData in my application for saving multiple tables (almost around 30), it is working fine but crashed randomly with this exception:

```
    [error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error. 
 Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2017-06-16 15:05:56.043490+0500 Sales CRM[619:85792]
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x1872c6fe0 0x185d28538 0x1872c6f28 0x1871e316c 0x1895c2028 0x1895c1218 0x1895c97d0 0x1895c019c 0x1001d6888 0x1001bb78c 0x1000a43d8 0x1878d034c 0x1878e8048 0x187d95814 0x187cda770 0x187ccab28 0x187d97bb0 0x100f85a10 0x100f932e8 0x100f89634 0x100f95630 0x100f9539c 0x186387100 0x186386cac)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have searched a lot but most of the solutions were in Objective C, and even I followed some of the solutions but none of it is working.

Here is my code:

```
 public class ServiceCalls : NSManagedObject {
  /*
    class func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateMOC.parent = moc

        privateMOC.perform({
            do {
                try privateMOC.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        })
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
   */ // tried this but didn't work as well

     class func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
```

Above is my context which is called every time I save or fetch any thing from any of the database. And below is how I save in coreData:

```
let context = getContext()
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "DoctorsDetail_Tbl", in: context)
    let newDoc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    newDoc.setValue(empid, forKey: "empId")
    newDoc.setValue(doctorid, forKey: "docId")



    //save the object
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved Doctors in Database yayy!")

    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: mark and as right if you found solution ..for better guidance to other so users.

Comment: @vaibhav solution didn't worked, still got the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes you are getting `nil` value** inside your datasource `(empid, doctorid)` which your want to insert in `coredata`

Check `nil` before you want to insert value to the database.

```
func test()  {
    for (key, value) in self {
        if let unwrappedValue = value.asOptional {
            print("Unwrapped value for '\(key)' is '\(unwrappedValue)'")
        } else {
            print("Value for '\(key)' is nil")
        }
    }
}
```

Uses:

```
var dict: [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2": nil,             // your program is unexpectedly crashing here 
    "key3": "somevalue"
]

dict.test()   // calling test fuction
```

---

**Filter nil in array:**

```
extension Array {
    static func filterNils(array: [T?]) -> [T] {
        return array.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    }
}
```

uses:

```
var array:[Int?] = [1, nil, 2, 3, nil]

Array.filterNils(array)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i got it but it is working perfectly fine most of the time, it just crashes randomly at times.

Comment: @shahtajkhalid, got your point so i suggest you to check nil value everytime inside your array or dict before insert.